# How to implement this event tracking to google analytics module

Tags: 7, google-analytics

I need to implement this event

```
setTimeout('pageTracker._trackEvent(\'NoBounce\',\'NoBounce\',\'Over 30 seconds\')',30000);
```

with the [Google Analytics event tracking module](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_et), I do not understand how to proceed and create this event, The event is useful for count a bounced visitor only if the visitor leaves before 30 secons, I need to add that event, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the way of add this event code in google analytics module.

Go to your admin->configs->google analytics

Go to advanced settings then open Custom Javascript code fieldset

Then in the field **Code snippet (after)**
add this snipppet:

```
setTimeout(“ga(‘send’,’event’,’Profitable Engagement’,’time on page more than 3 minutes’)”, 180000);
```

I modified the code snippet in order to fit universal analytics code that is the one used in the Drupal google analytics module.

After that you will see how your bounce rates are more accurate

Answer (score 2):

The GA Event Tracking module is designed to react to a number of different binded JS events. You're limited by what [DOM events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/) that jQuery can bind to. As such, there is no `settimeout` event.

One solution that comes to mind is adding some custom JS to the standard [GA module](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics). Go to configuration page under the `Custom Javascript Code` in the `Advanced Settings` fieldset. There you can add what custom JS needed to trigger your setTimeout GA event.

Comment: Ok so should I add it as it is? or I need to change something in the script?

Comment: I think depending on your setup you might need the ga function. That's really outside the scope of Drupal Answers.

Comment: FWIW, in the event tracking I used with UA I use something like this for triggering event tracking: `var fieldObject = {'hitType': 'event', 'eventCategory': Category, 'eventAction': Action }; ga("set", fieldObject); ga('send', fieldObject);`